# Form field renders differently on Mac

Tags: css, forms, cross-browser, field

[image: text fields show inset shadow on Mac, but not on PC]

I'm trying to standardize the appearance of my text fields and textarea. Below is an image of how my form fields display on Mac, but the textarea displays without the inset shadow. On Windows, the text fields and textarea display the same.

I've tried various CSS combinations to standardize them, with no luck. I'm fine with either the inset version or the non-inset version.

In case this helps anyone, the form is a WordPress Gravity Form.

Comment: although i don't know the answer to your question, [here](http://formalize.me/) is a library for standardizing forms.  possibly the answer lies in their source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically this can be solved by setting a background image for the input boxes. If you're trying to stay a little more simplistic, figure out where things are inconsistent, and explicitly set them in your CSS.

```
input.inputbox { 
    background: url(input.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; 
    width: 150px; 
    height: 30px; 
    ... /* fonts, padding, borders, etc */
}
```

Comment: Although I didn't try that css, the advice is correct. I finally found where things were inconsistent, and the textarea had 1px solid #a4a4a4 specified and the input fields did not. In Mac Chrome, without specifying css, the user agent gave it an inset.

Answer (score 0):

the only way to achieve this is using javascript. I would recommend you 
[Formalize me][1] 
[1]: http://formalize.me/ jQuery plugin